# What is the most efficient configuration for Fireworks?

Tags: curiosity

Fireworks seem to destroy a 7x7 square around them. They can also trigger other fireworks nearby. What is the most efficient configuration of fireworks to clear the largest area?

Comment: They trigger others, but is it actually making it bigger, or just saving a tap?

Comment: You get a bonus when they trigger others.